# Textbox to work with upper & lower cases

Tags: vb.net

I have a textbox that looks for words from another textbox. Unless I have typed the same exact word with the same exact upper or lower case, it wont find the word. visual basic.net

how do i make the textbox be able to to accept weather the words it finds has upper and lower cases, so if i search for the word " John" and the textbox has the word "john" it will work, notice the "J" is upper case.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
If TextBox2.Text.ToLower.Contains(TextBox1.Text.ToLower) Then
    '[...]
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
Textbox1.Text.ToUpper().Contains(Textbox2.Text.ToUpper())
```

However, for future reference I strongly suggest you try things first. Post what you tried together with your explanation. Just asking for code like you just did will not be accepted, especially on easy tasks like this.

Answer (score 0):

Use IndexOf and a case insensitive search

```
If Textbox1.Text.IndexOf(Textbox2.Test, StringComparison.InvariantIgnoreCase) >= 0 Then
    'The string was found, do something with it.
End If
```